# NoMethodError: undefined method `to_sym' for PDF::Reader

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf-reader

When am trying to get the page text for a pdf, getting `NoMethod error` as below.

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `to_sym' for #<PDF::Reader::Stream:0x007fc8430e84a0>
```

Here is my piece of code

```
PDF::Reader.open(../location/..) do |reader|
   reader.pages.each do |page|
     do_something if page.text.size > 100
     do_something if page.text.size < 100
   end
end
```

page.text in the code returning the error.

Comment: Can you show a little more of your stack trace? it seems improbable, that `PDF::Reader` would call `#to_sym` on its `Stream`, can you provide some line info where this should happen?

Comment: On digging up the gem...actual issue is in calling page callback method on each receiver(which is PDF::Reader::PageTextReceiver object). But not sure why its throwing the to_sym error.

Comment: Is there nothing more to the stacktrace you get? You should post some more of it if there are any, after all this *is* Stackoverflow and I first discovered the site because I pasted some error message directly into google, so you should provide more of it.